# Is the query acting like it should?

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I posted the question below:

"""

Here is a simplified version of my table:

It contains the columns
`employee_id  column2  column3   x   y`
and they are all `NUMERIC`

I am having trouble writing a complicated MySQL query. I want to get all the `employeeid` and `column3` values for all employees that have the same value in `column2` as another employee and have DIFFERENT values for `x` and `y` PAIR from every other employee. For example, if the following 4 rows were in table:

```
2 100 123.456 5 7
1 234 123.456 5 7
3 100 456.789 5 10
4 100 123.456 5 7
```

The rows `2 100 123.456 5 7` and `3 100 456.789 5 10` should be obtained because they have different employee ids (`2` vs `3`), the same value for `column2` (`100` and `100`), and different `x`, `y` pair: (Employee 2 has `x` = 5 and `y` = 7, which is distinct from `x` = 5 and `y` = 10).

How can I compare the documents of table with other documents within itself?

"""

Somebody responded with the following query, which I adapted for my table:

```
SELECT truncate(column2, 2)
from TABLE t1
JOIN TABLE t2
ON t1.id <> t2.id
AND t1.TIV_2011 = t1.TIV_2011
AND (t1.X <> t2.X OR t1.X <> t2.Y)
```

I am still not getting the result I expect, so I'm wondering if this query is doing what I think it's doing or if it's missing something.

Comment: Don't post a dupe. If the answer you got in the previous qusetion isn't the solution, then DON'T accept it.

Comment: Yes, just explain why isnt giving you the right answer so we can help you